# Получить имя пользователя в телеграм боте

Tags: python, бот, python-telegram-bot

Здравствуйте пишу бота на Python- pyTelegramBotApi. Нужно, что бы бот, получал имя юзера. В первой функции при нажатии старт берется имя пользователя, а в следующих висветливается имя бота. Решила создать переменную вне функциях и все равно выводит имя бота.

```
user = bot.get_me()
name = user.first_name
print(name)
```

Answer (score 2):

Функция `getMe()`, которую вы используете, предназначена для получения информации о боте. Но вам нужно имя человека, отправившего сообщение.

В [API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) сообщений есть `from` атрибут (`from_user`), который содержит объект User , содержащий сведения о человеке, отправившем сообщение.

Так что вам больше повезет с чем-то вроде `name = message.from_user.first_name`

[Дубль вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50521031/how-to-get-the-users-name-in-telegram-bot)